# Oracle incorrectly looking in TNS Names: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm trying to make a connection to an oracle database with cx_Oracle but am getting the following error message:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I'm using a connection string such as this one:

```
'xxxx/pw@lonod-com:1221/LNOUND_USER.uk.something.com'
```

The connection string is definitely correct as it is working from a different computer on the same network. I can also connect to the database when using Oracle SQL Developer, it's simply not working from Python.

I suspect that for some reason it keeps looking for a TNS Name entry, which I am not using. Is there a flag somewhere that could cause cx_Oracle to keep looking for a TNS name entry or what else could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this occur if you have a sqlnet.ora configuration file that does not include the EZCONNECT option in the names.directory_path configuration variable. Below are a few ways to check what you are using. You can also test this connection string with SQL*Plus -- if it works with SQL*Plus it will work with cx_Oracle as well.

1) If you have the environment variable TNS_ADMIN set, its value indicates where Oracle searches for configuration files. If not and you have a full Oracle client installed it will look inside $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

2) If you have a full Oracle client installed you can also use the tnsping utility to determine what Oracle is using and from what configuration files it is reading.

3) If you have a sqlnet.ora file in the location Oracle is searching for configuration files, then look for the names.directory_path= line in the file. If it is found, it needs to look something like this:

```
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Hope that helps!